# Task Scheduler .bat file creating wrong folder, while manually running it creating correct folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

[image]When I am running .bat file manually it is creating the right folder, but when same file I am scheduling and running through Task Scheduler it is not creating folder as expected.
Below is the main code for creating folder.

```
ECHO OFF
SET TMPSCRIPT=E:\backup\full\bkp_temp.txt
CD /D E:\backup\full
set temp=%DATE:/=%
set tem=%TIME%
set dirname=%temp:~4,2%%temp:~6,2%%temp:~8,4%%tem:~0,2%%tem:~3,2%
mkdir %dirname%
```

When Scheduling for next day it is creating time directory separately.

Comment: Apart from the fact that `%temp:~8,4%` doesn't make sense when `%temp%` is only 8 characters long, this should work. Which directory is it creating and at which hour is it scheduled to run?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please find below screen shot

Comment: If you see the output, I scheduled to run it every Sunday at 3 AM . It created two folders as per screenshot. But if run this script manually it created correctly , please see those output as mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

Your batch job must have too many commas. You are most likely executing the
equivalent of:

```
mkdir dir1,dir2
```

which creates two separate directories.

If you can't find the problem, please add your *exact* code to your post.

Comment: No..not exactly, if this is the case then manually it shouldn't create correctly

Comment: I suggest changing the command to `mkdir "%dirname%"`.

Comment: Acknowledged, will try that.